# Installing ROS on Nao and Peoplebot

Tags: nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. how would i install ROS on a Nao and Peoplebot? Is it compatible?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11334/installing-ros-on-nao-and-peoplebot/) by [tmahmood](https://answers.ros.org/users/1130/tmahmood/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-09-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check the ROS Robots page at: http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots
The Nao can be easily integrated with the [Nao stack](http://www.ros.org/wiki/nao) but there is no official support from Aldebaran and it requires some work with crosscompilation to run ROS directly on the robot.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2011-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have an adapted stack for the peoplebot, we control this one over the serial connection and carry around a beagleboard to control it.

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-09-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1